# Eclipse - remote debugging and segfault in dl_main at rtld.c

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I want to debug my application written in C++ in Eclipse via network. I followed this tutorial http://janaxelson.com/eclipse5.htm but when debugging starts it gives me strange segmentation fault. Full log:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.9-1ubuntu1) 7.9
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
0xb7fdf0d0 in print_statistics (rtld_total_timep=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:2594
2594    rtld.c: No such file or directory.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7fe129f in dl_main (phdr=0x8048034, phnum=9, user_entry=0xbffff6ec, auxv=0xbffff7e0) at rtld.c:2182
2182    in rtld.c
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

My setup is
Ubuntu 15.04, gcc version 4.9.2, gdb 7.9, Eclipse Mars

Target machine:
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, gdb 7.7.1, gdbserver 7.7.1